# Grabbing value from button element and using that value to call a specific WordPress post within a modal

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, bootstrap-modal, custom-post-type

I am trying to work on a task manager plugin for WordPress that allows certain user types(we can call managers) assign tasks to other users(employee) and also lets either type of user make their own tasks. I've made a custom post type for this, with the needed meta-fields: assigner user-id, assigned user-id, task status(un-read, in progress, completed), task description, task type(assigned or personal) as well as the due date.

I am currently able to display the tasks to specific users based on these fields and their set parameters when the task gets created^^. I am also able to sort between assigned task and personal tasks. What I want to do is have the assigned tasks first display as something like this:

[new-unread task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn4Go.png)

And when the user clicks on view(which holds the post id as a value), the task appears as a modal which will then also change the status of the task(from unread to in progress).

Everything shown in the image above is through "the loop" for the "task" post type but im unsure of how to pass the post id of the "task" to a modal without creating a modal within the loop which I feel would create redundant code (unless this is the best option?). My guess is to use js(ajax?) to pass the value of the "view" button to php, but I'm really unsure on how to do this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna to use AJAX you can make code like this:

In html view:

```
<button class="view-task" data-post-id="<?php $post->ID; ?>">View</button>
```

In js you can use it:

```
$('.view-task').off('click').on('click', e => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log(e.target);//Here you can see your button
console.log(e.target.data('post-id');//Here you can see your post ID ad use it for AJAX
}
```